# Textbox allow more than 3 values

Tags: c#

I have an issue with an textbox, once it was to accept just 3 values know i have update it to nvarchar(MAX) I updated the EntityModelDB but still after this i'm receivein an error when i add more than 3 values in my textbox
Here is my code

```
if (!Regex.Match(item.treatments_code, @"^[A-Z0-9\-]{6}$").Success)
{
    ret = false;
    errors = errors.Concat(new string[] { language.text003 }).ToArray();
}
```

Here is my error

An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in DGUIGHF.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Invalid code format. 3 character, uppercase letters [A-Z] or numbers [0-9], or minus '-'.

FormTreatments.cs

```
using DG.Data.Model.Helpers;
using DG.DentneD.Forms.Objects;
using DG.DentneD.Helpers;
using DG.DentneD.Model;
using DG.DentneD.Model.Entity;
using DG.UI.GHF;
using SMcMaster;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Zuby.ADGV;

namespace DG.DentneD.Forms
```

{
    public partial class FormTreatments : DGUIGHFForm
    {
        private DentneDModel _dentnedModel = null;

```
    private TabElement tabElement_tabTreatments = new TabElement();
    private TabElement tabElement_tabTreatmentsPrices = new TabElement();

    private readonly BoxLoader _boxLoader = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor
    /// </summary>
    public FormTreatments()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        (new TabOrderManager(this)).SetTabOrder(TabOrderManager.TabScheme.AcrossFirst);

        Initialize(Program.uighfApplication);

        _dentnedModel = new DentneDModel();
        _dentnedModel.LanguageHelper.LoadFromFile(Program.uighfApplication.LanguageFilename);

        _boxLoader = new BoxLoader(_dentnedModel);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Add components language
    /// </summary>
    public override void AddLanguageComponents()
    {
        //main
        LanguageHelper.AddComponent(this);
        LanguageHelper.AddComponent(treatmentsidDataGridViewTextBoxColumn, this.GetType().Name, "HeaderText");
        LanguageHelper.AddComponent(nameDataGridViewTextBoxColumn, this.GetType().Name, "HeaderText");
        LanguageHelper.AddComponent(codeDataGridViewTextBoxColumn, this.GetType().Name, "HeaderText");
        LanguageHelper.AddComponent(typeDataGridViewTextBoxColumn, this.GetType().Name, "HeaderText");
        LanguageHelper.AddComponent(button_export);
        //tabTreatments
        LanguageHelper.AddComponent(tabPage_tabTreatments);
        LanguageHelper.AddComponent(button_tabTreatments_new);
        LanguageHelper.AddComponent(button_tabTreatments_edit);
        LanguageHelper.AddComponent(button_tabTreatments_delete);
        LanguageHelper.AddComponent(button_tabTreatments_save);
        LanguageHelper.AddComponent(button_tabTreatments_cancel);
        LanguageHelper.AddComponent(treatments_idLabel);
        LanguageHelper.AddComponent(treatments_nameLabel);
        LanguageHelper.AddComponent(treatments_codeLabel);
        LanguageHelper.AddComponent(treatmentstypes_idLabel);
        LanguageHelper.AddComponent(treatments_mexpirationLabel);
        LanguageHelper.AddComponent(treatments_mexpirationinfoLabel);
        LanguageHelper.AddComponent(treatments_priceLabel);
        LanguageHelper.AddComponent(treatments_notesLabel);
        LanguageHelper.AddComponent(taxes_idLabel);
        LanguageHelper.AddComponent(treatments_isunitpriceCheckBox);
        LanguageHelper.AddComponent(button_tabTreatments_unsettaxesid);
        //tabTreatmentsPrices
        LanguageHelper.AddComponent(tabPage_tabTreatmentsPrices);
        LanguageHelper.AddComponent(label_tabTreatmentsPrices_filterpriceslists);
        LanguageHelper.AddComponent(treatmentspricesidDataGridViewTextBoxColumn, this.GetType().Name, "HeaderText");
        LanguageHelper.AddComponent(pricelistDataGridViewTextBoxColumn, this.GetType().Name, "HeaderText");
        LanguageHelper.AddComponent(priceDataGridViewTextBoxColumn, this.GetType().Name, "HeaderText");
        LanguageHelper.AddComponent(button_tabTreatmentsPrices_new);
        LanguageHelper.AddComponent(button_tabTreatmentsPrices_edit);
        LanguageHelper.AddComponent(button_tabTreatmentsPrices_delete);
        LanguageHelper.AddComponent(button_tabTreatmentsPrices_save);
        LanguageHelper.AddComponent(button_tabTreatmentsPrices_cancel);
        LanguageHelper.AddComponent(treatmentsprices_idLabel);
        LanguageHelper.AddComponent(treatmentspriceslists_idLabel);
        LanguageHelper.AddComponent(treatmentsprices_priceLabel);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Form language dictionary
    /// </summary>
    public class FormLanguage : IDGUIGHFLanguage
    {
        public string exportColumnCode = "Code";
        public string exportColumnType = "Type";
        public string exportColumnName = "Name";
        public string exportColumnPrice = "Price";
        public string exportSaveFileDialogTitle = "Save an Excel File";
        public string exportErrorMessage = "Error writing file '{0}'.";
        public string exportErrorTitle = "Error";
        public string exportSuccessMessage = "File created. Do you want to open it with your default application?";
        public string exportSuccessTitle = "Open";
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Form language
    /// </summary>
    public FormLanguage language = new FormLanguage();

    /// <summary>
    /// Initialize TabElements
    /// </summary>
    protected override void InitializeTabElements()
    {
        //set Readonly OnSetEditingMode for Controls
        DisableReadonlyCheckOnSetEditingModeControlCollection.Add(typeof(DataGridView));
        DisableReadonlyCheckOnSetEditingModeControlCollection.Add(typeof(AdvancedDataGridView));

        //set Main BindingSource
        BindingSourceMain = vTreatmentsBindingSource;
        GetDataSourceMain = GetDataSource_main;

        //set Main TabControl
        TabControlMain = tabControl_main;

        //set Main Panels
        PanelFiltersMain = panel_filters;
        PanelListMain = panel_list;
        PanelsExtraMain = null;

        //set tabTreatments
        tabElement_tabTreatments = new TabElement()
        {
            TabPageElement = tabPage_tabTreatments,
            ElementItem = new TabElement.TabElementItem()
            {
                PanelData = panel_tabTreatments_data,
                PanelActions = panel_tabTreatments_actions,
                PanelUpdates = panel_tabTreatments_updates,

                ParentBindingSourceList = vTreatmentsBindingSource,
                GetParentDataSourceList = GetDataSource_main,

                BindingSourceEdit = treatmentsBindingSource,
                GetDataSourceEdit = GetDataSourceEdit_tabTreatments,
                AfterSaveAction = AfterSaveAction_tabTreatments,

                AddButton = button_tabTreatments_new,
                UpdateButton = button_tabTreatments_edit,
                RemoveButton = button_tabTreatments_delete,
                SaveButton = button_tabTreatments_save,
                CancelButton = button_tabTreatments_cancel,

                Add = Add_tabTreatments,
                Update = Update_tabTreatments,
                Remove = Remove_tabTreatments
            }
        };

        //set tabTreatmentsPrices
        tabElement_tabTreatmentsPrices = new TabElement()
        {
            TabPageElement = tabPage_tabTreatmentsPrices,
            ElementListItem = new TabElement.TabElementListItem()
            {
                PanelFilters = panel_tabTreatmentsPrices_filters,
                PanelList = panel_tabTreatmentsPrices_list,

                PanelData = panel_tabTreatmentsPrices_data,
                PanelActions = panel_tabTreatmentsPrices_actions,
                PanelUpdates = panel_tabTreatmentsPrices_updates,

                BindingSourceList = vTreatmentsPricesBindingSource,
                GetDataSourceList = GetDataSourceList_tabTreatmentsPrices,

                BindingSourceEdit = treatmentspricesBindingSource,
                GetDataSourceEdit = GetDataSourceEdit_tabTreatmentsPrices,
                AfterSaveAction = AfterSaveAction_tabTreatmentsPrices,

                AddButton = button_tabTreatmentsPrices_new,
                IsAddButtonDefaultClickEventAttached = false,
                UpdateButton = button_tabTreatmentsPrices_edit,
                RemoveButton = button_tabTreatmentsPrices_delete,
                SaveButton = button_tabTreatmentsPrices_save,
                CancelButton = button_tabTreatmentsPrices_cancel,

                Add = Add_tabTreatmentsPrices,
                Update = Update_tabTreatmentsPrices,
                Remove = Remove_tabTreatmentsPrices
            }
        };

        //set Elements
        TabElements.Add(tabElement_tabTreatments);
        TabElements.Add(tabElement_tabTreatmentsPrices);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Loader
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void FormTreatments_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        IsBindingSourceLoading = true;
        advancedDataGridView_main.SortASC(advancedDataGridView_main.Columns[2]);
        advancedDataGridView_main.SortASC(advancedDataGridView_main.Columns[1]);
        advancedDataGridView_main.SortASC(advancedDataGridView_main.Columns[3]);
        IsBindingSourceLoading = false;




        PreloadView();

        ReloadView();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Preload View
    /// </summary>
    private void PreloadView()
    {
        IsBindingSourceLoading = true;

        _boxLoader.LoadComboBoxTreatmentsTypes(treatmentstypes_idComboBox);
        _boxLoader.LoadComboBoxTreatmentsPricesLists(treatmentspriceslists_idComboBox);
        _boxLoader.LoadComboBoxTaxes(taxes_idComboBox);

        _boxLoader.LoadComboBoxFilterTreatmentsPricesLists(comboBox_tabTreatmentsPrices_filterPriceslists);

        IsBindingSourceLoading = false;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Reset all the tab datagrid
    /// </summary>
    private void ResetTabsDataGrid()
    {
        IsBindingSourceLoading = true;
        advancedDataGridView_tabTreatmentsPrices_list.CleanFilterAndSort();
        advancedDataGridView_tabTreatmentsPrices_list.SortASC(advancedDataGridView_tabTreatmentsPrices_list.Columns[1]);
        IsBindingSourceLoading = false;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get main list DataSource
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private object GetDataSource_main()
    {
        ResetTabsDataGrid();

        IEnumerable<VTreatments> vTreatments =
            _dentnedModel.Treatments.List().Select(
            r => new VTreatments
            {
                treatments_id = r.treatments_id,
                code = r.treatments_code,

                type = _dentnedModel.TreatmentsTypes.Find(r.treatmentstypes_id).treatmentstypes_name,
                name = r.treatments_name
            }).ToList();

        return DGDataTableUtils.ToDataTable<VTreatments>(vTreatments);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Main list current element changed hanlder
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void vTreatmentsBindingSource_CurrentChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsBindingSourceLoading)
            return;

        //get current itme
        int treatments_id = -1;
        if (vTreatmentsBindingSource.Current != null)
        {
            treatments_id = (((DataRowView)vTreatmentsBindingSource.Current).Row).Field<int>("treatments_id");
        }

        //set treatments fields
        treatments_mexpirationTextBox.Text = "";
        if (treatments_id != -1)
        {
            treatments treatment = _dentnedModel.Treatments.Find(treatments_id);
            treatments_mexpirationTextBox.Text = treatment.treatments_mexpiration.ToString();
        }

        //reset treatments prices filter
        comboBox_tabTreatmentsPrices_filterPriceslists.SelectedIndex = -1;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Export click
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void button_export_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string filename = null;
        SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
        saveFileDialog.Filter = "Excel|*.xls";
        saveFileDialog.Title = language.exportSaveFileDialogTitle; ;
        saveFileDialog.ShowDialog();
        filename = saveFileDialog.FileName;
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(filename))
        {
            Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;

            DataTable datatable = new DataTable();
            datatable.Clear();
            datatable.Columns.Add(language.exportColumnCode);
            datatable.Columns.Add(language.exportColumnType);
            datatable.Columns.Add(language.exportColumnName);
            datatable.Columns.Add(language.exportColumnPrice);
            foreach (treatmentspriceslists treatmentspriceslist in _dentnedModel.TreatmentsPricesLists.List().OrderBy(r => r.treatmentspriceslists_name))
            {
                datatable.Columns.Add(language.exportColumnPrice + "-" + treatmentspriceslist.treatmentspriceslists_id);
            }

            //add datatable columns
            foreach (treatments treatment in _dentnedModel.Treatments.List().OrderBy(r => r.treatments_code))
            {
                DataRow row = datatable.NewRow();
                row[language.exportColumnCode] = treatment.treatments_code;
                row[language.exportColumnType] = _dentnedModel.TreatmentsTypes.Find(treatment.treatmentstypes_id).treatmentstypes_name;
                row[language.exportColumnName] = treatment.treatments_name;
                row[language.exportColumnPrice] = treatment.treatments_price;
                foreach (treatmentspriceslists treatmentspriceslist in _dentnedModel.TreatmentsPricesLists.List().OrderBy(r => r.treatmentspriceslists_name))
                {
                    Nullable<decimal> price = null;
                    treatmentsprices treatmentsprice = _dentnedModel.TreatmentsPrices.FirstOrDefault(r => r.treatments_id == treatment.treatments_id && r.treatmentspriceslists_id == treatmentspriceslist.treatmentspriceslists_id);
                    if (treatmentsprice != null)
                    {
                        price = treatmentsprice.treatmentsprices_price;
                    }
                    row[language.exportColumnPrice + "-" + treatmentspriceslist.treatmentspriceslists_id] = price;
                }
                datatable.Rows.Add(row);
            }

            Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;

            //export to excel
            DataSet dataset = new DataSet();
            dataset.Tables.Add(datatable);
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(filename))
            {
                try
                {
                    ExcelExporter.CreateWorkbook(filename, dataset);
                }
                catch
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(String.Format(language.exportErrorMessage, filename), language.exportErrorTitle, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                    return;
                }

                if (MessageBox.Show(language.exportSuccessMessage, language.exportSuccessTitle, MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button2) == DialogResult.Yes)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Process.Start(filename);
                    }
                    catch { }
                }
            }
        }
    }


    #region tabTreatments

    /// <summary>
    /// Load the tab DataSource
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private object GetDataSourceEdit_tabTreatments()
    {
        return DGUIGHFData.LoadEntityFromCurrentBindingSource<treatments, DentneDModel>(_dentnedModel.Treatments, vTreatmentsBindingSource, new string[] { "treatments_id" });
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Do actions after Save
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="item"></param>
    private void AfterSaveAction_tabTreatments(object item)
    {
        DGUIGHFData.SetBindingSourcePosition<treatments, DentneDModel>(_dentnedModel.Treatments, item, vTreatmentsBindingSource);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Add an item
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="item"></param>
    private void Add_tabTreatments(object item)

    {

        DGUIGHFData.Add<treatments, DentneDModel>(_dentnedModel.Treatments, item);
        //update mexpiration
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(treatments_mexpirationTextBox.Text))
            ((treatments)item).treatments_mexpiration = Convert.ToByte(treatments_mexpirationTextBox.Text);
        else
            ((treatments)item).treatments_mexpiration = null;


    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Update an item
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="item"></param>
    private void Update_tabTreatments(object item)
    {
        //update mexpiration
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(treatments_mexpirationTextBox.Text))
            ((treatments)item).treatments_mexpiration = Convert.ToByte(treatments_mexpirationTextBox.Text);
        else
            ((treatments)item).treatments_mexpiration = null;

        DGUIGHFData.Update<treatments, DentneDModel>(_dentnedModel.Treatments, item);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Remove an item
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="item"></param>
    private void Remove_tabTreatments(object item)
    {
        DGUIGHFData.Remove<treatments, DentneDModel>(_dentnedModel.Treatments, item);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Unset taxes_id
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void button_tabTreatments_unsettaxesid_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        taxes_idComboBox.SelectedIndex = -1;
    }

    #endregion


    #region tabTreatmentsPrices

    /// <summary>
    /// Get tab list DataSource
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private object GetDataSourceList_tabTreatmentsPrices()
    {
        object ret = null;

        //get current treatment
        int treatments_id = -1;
        if (vTreatmentsBindingSource.Current != null)
        {
            treatments_id = (((DataRowView)vTreatmentsBindingSource.Current).Row).Field<int>("treatments_id");
        }

        //get treatments
        List<treatmentsprices> treatmentspricesl = new List<treatmentsprices>();
        if (comboBox_tabTreatmentsPrices_filterPriceslists.SelectedIndex != -1 && comboBox_tabTreatmentsPrices_filterPriceslists.SelectedIndex != 0)
        {
            int treatmentspriceslists_id = Convert.ToInt32(comboBox_tabTreatmentsPrices_filterPriceslists.SelectedValue);
            treatmentspricesl = _dentnedModel.TreatmentsPrices.List(r => r.treatments_id == treatments_id && r.treatmentspriceslists_id == treatmentspriceslists_id).ToList();
        }
        else
            treatmentspricesl = _dentnedModel.TreatmentsPrices.List(r => r.treatments_id == treatments_id).ToList();
        IEnumerable<VTreatmentsPrices> vTreatmentsPrices =
        treatmentspricesl.Select(
        r => new VTreatmentsPrices
        {
            treatmentsprices_id = r.treatmentsprices_id,
            price = (double)r.treatmentsprices_price,
            pricelist = _dentnedModel.TreatmentsPricesLists.Find(r.treatmentspriceslists_id).treatmentspriceslists_name
        }).ToList();

        ret = DGDataTableUtils.ToDataTable<VTreatmentsPrices>(vTreatmentsPrices);

        return ret;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Load the tab DataSource
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private object GetDataSourceEdit_tabTreatmentsPrices()
    {
        return DGUIGHFData.LoadEntityFromCurrentBindingSource<treatmentsprices, DentneDModel>(_dentnedModel.TreatmentsPrices, vTreatmentsPricesBindingSource, new string[] { "treatmentsprices_id" });
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Do actions after Save
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="item"></param>
    private void AfterSaveAction_tabTreatmentsPrices(object item)
    {
        DGUIGHFData.SetBindingSourcePosition<treatmentsprices, DentneDModel>(_dentnedModel.TreatmentsPrices, item, vTreatmentsPricesBindingSource);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Add an item
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="item"></param>
    private void Add_tabTreatmentsPrices(object item)
    {
        DGUIGHFData.Add<treatmentsprices, DentneDModel>(_dentnedModel.TreatmentsPrices, item);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Update an item
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="item"></param>
    private void Update_tabTreatmentsPrices(object item)
    {
        DGUIGHFData.Update<treatmentsprices, DentneDModel>(_dentnedModel.TreatmentsPrices, item);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Remove an item
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="item"></param>
    private void Remove_tabTreatmentsPrices(object item)
    {
        DGUIGHFData.Remove<treatmentsprices, DentneDModel>(_dentnedModel.TreatmentsPrices, item);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// New tab button handler
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void button_tabTreatmentsPrices_new_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (vTreatmentsBindingSource.Current != null)
        {
            if (AddClick(tabElement_tabTreatmentsPrices))
            {
                ((treatmentsprices)treatmentspricesBindingSource.Current).treatments_id = (((DataRowView)vTreatmentsBindingSource.Current).Row).Field<int>("treatments_id");
                if (comboBox_tabTreatmentsPrices_filterPriceslists.SelectedIndex != -1 && comboBox_tabTreatmentsPrices_filterPriceslists.SelectedIndex != 0)
                {
                    ((treatmentsprices)treatmentspricesBindingSource.Current).treatmentspriceslists_id = Convert.ToInt32(comboBox_tabTreatmentsPrices_filterPriceslists.SelectedValue);
                    treatmentspriceslists_idComboBox.Enabled = false;
                }
                treatmentspricesBindingSource.ResetBindings(true);
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Treatments prices changed
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void comboBox_tabTreatmentsPrices_filterPriceslists_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsBindingSourceLoading)
            return;

        ReloadTab(tabElement_tabTreatmentsPrices);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Treatments lists changed
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void treatmentspriceslists_idComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsBindingSourceLoading)
            return;

        if (treatmentspriceslists_idComboBox.SelectedIndex != -1 && (tabElement_tabTreatmentsPrices.CurrentEditingMode == EditingMode.C || tabElement_tabTreatmentsPrices.CurrentEditingMode == EditingMode.U))
        {
            int treatments_id = -1;
            if (vTreatmentsBindingSource.Current != null)
            {
                treatments_id = (((DataRowView)vTreatmentsBindingSource.Current).Row).Field<int>("treatments_id");
            }
            if (treatments_id != -1)
            {
                treatments treatments = _dentnedModel.Treatments.Find(treatments_id);
                treatmentspriceslists treatmentspriceslist = _dentnedModel.TreatmentsPricesLists.Find(treatmentspriceslists_idComboBox.SelectedValue);
                if (treatments != null && treatmentspriceslist != null)
                {
                    ((treatmentsprices)treatmentspricesBindingSource.Current).treatmentspriceslists_id = treatmentspriceslist.treatmentspriceslists_id;
                    ((treatmentsprices)treatmentspricesBindingSource.Current).treatmentsprices_price = Math.Round(treatments.treatments_price * treatmentspriceslist.treatmentspriceslists_multiplier, 2);
                }
                treatmentspricesBindingSource.ResetBindings(true);
            }
        }
    }



    #endregion

    private void button_tabTreatments_save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void treatments_codeTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

}

Comment: `-` has to be the first item inside square braces unless its part of a range.

Comment: I dont know how to resolve it ?

Comment: Well, it has to be the first thing inside the square brackets... so move it to the front?

Comment: how has this any connection to a textbox, and if so which and from which UI-framework. WinForms, WPF, etc.

Comment: Nope, it doesn't have to be the first character, if it is properly escaped, which it is.

Comment: Please also let us know, what text is actually being input, so we can tell you, why the regular expression is NOT matching.

Comment: It has to be numeric value *   more than 3 numbers that actually are know !

Comment: Your regex expects exactly 6 characters.

Comment: If you only have a small number of allowed values you should use a CombBox.

Comment: Yes. i have changed it to see if it works .. actually it db i have added it (nvarchar(50),not null

Comment: I need text box and it must allow more than 3 value example (20) or more ..

Comment: What do you mean by "more than 3 value"? Do you mean the `Text` property must be more than 3 characters? Or are you allowing multiple values (separated by some special character) in a single string?

Comment: Yes.. it just allows me to add 3 characters in db i have made it nvarchar(50) so just the code isnt right..  ill need example when i add  123456..

Comment: I think, we'll need to see the code defining your textbox.

Comment: By the way in [mcve], the _"Minimal"_ part is important.  A better way to have posted this question would be to create a simple demo app with one control in it that has whatever constraint you want.  You'll find that more people will read your question if it does contains (seemingly) hundreds of lines of code.  I will also focus people on the issue you are asking about.

Comment: I realize that English is likely not a native language for you.  However, I suspect very few people are sure that they understand what you mean by "Textbox allow more than 3 values", "I need text box and it must allow more than 3 value example (20) or more" and "Yes.. it just allows me to add 3 characters in db i have made it nvarchar(50) so just the code isnt right.. ill need example when i add 123456".  I strongly suggest you post examples of what you expect your Textbox to accept and examples of what it should reject (and why, for all cases).

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest reading up on Regular Expressions and download a Regex tool such as Expresso (http://www.ultrapico.com/expresso.htm), or use one of the various online Regex evaluation sites.

"^[A-Z0-9\-]{6}$"

This conflicts with what you are saying about "expecting 3 characters". This Regex will expect 6, and only 6 characters ranging from A-Z, 0-9, and-or a "-". The text message that is added to the errors collection may still say "3 characters" but that is a misleading message that needs to be updated. Whatever changes you do to the regular expression, you should also update the message behind language.text003, wherever that is coming from. (Resource file, database, etc.)

If the updated text box can accept any number of characters, but still needs to be A-Z, 0-9, and "-" then:

"^[A-Z0-9\-]*"

If you want to impose a maximum of 20 characters for example:

"^[A-Z0-9\-]{0,20}$"

If you want a minimum of 6 and maximum of 20:

"^[A-Z0-9\-]{6,20}$"

If you just want to accept any string and remove the character restrictions all-together, then delete that whole `if` block.

Comment: Can i remove the restrictions .. it doesnt matter how many characters i added... ?  Bcuz i receive error

Comment: Not sure that I or anyone else can answer that question. That depends on the requirements for the application around that field. If there is meant to be no restriction to the characters entered (length or which characters are allowed) then there is no need for that Regex and its associated error message. It was there for a reason though. Requirements and reasons change, but I'd be rather concerned about someone changing code they don't first understand.

Comment: Yes know i can add more values but when i want to add treatment to client ti shows me error

Comment: I'd be looking to make a case to your employer to hire an experienced local developer short term to review issues like this and mentor you. Unfortunately StackOverflow (or this area of it) is predominantly in English and it's very difficult to understand what your exact issue is and how best to help. 15 minutes with an experienced dev in your native tongue and you'd be sorted out.